# click function for dynamically created element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

The click functionality in my app is not working for dynamically created elements in **angular js**.

Here's my code:

HTML Code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtl">
    <p>
        Click is not working in table
    </p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="value in person.records">
            <td>{{value.firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{value.age}}</td>
            <td ng-bind-html="value.button"></td>
        </tr>
    </table><br />
    <br />
    <p>
        When I click on Click button, My function should be call like below
    </p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="trailClick()">Click</button>

</div>
```

JS Code: In the table, when I click on "click button", I'm not getting the functionality I want.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtl", function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.trailClick = function() {
        alert('Clicked ');
    }
    $scope.person = {
        "records": [{
            firstname: "John",
            lastname: "Doe",
            age: 50,
            eyecolor: "blue"
        }, {
            firstname: "Dev",
            lastname: "Raj",
            age: 50,
            eyecolor: "black"
        }]
    };

    var cln_btn = '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="trailClick()">Click</button>';
    for (var x = 0; x < $scope.person.records.length; x++) {
        $scope.person.records[x].button = $sce.trustAsHtml(cln_btn);
    }
});
```

Comment: we need more info. did you include the .js file inside your view? do you have any errors in console?

Comment: shouldn't it be console.alert()?

Comment: Yes. I include angular.js & Sanitize.js files in my app. There is no errors in console. Please find code in below path: 
https://jsfiddle.net/habibullah/vkby5fkt/14/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find plenty of information about this issue looking on stackoverflow.

In short you can create your own directive or install [this one](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile)

```
angular-bind-html-compile
```

include it to your application as a dependency:

```
angular-bind-html-compile
```

and call it as

```
bind-html-compile
```

In code would be like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ngSanitize@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-bind-html-compile.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize', 'angular-bind-html-compile']);
    app.controller("myCtl", function($scope, $sce, $compile) {
        $scope.trailClick = function() {
            alert('Clicked ');
        }
        $scope.person = {
            "records": [{
                firstname: "John",
                lastname: "Doe",
                age: 50,
                eyecolor: "blue"
            }, {
                firstname: "Dev",
                lastname: "Raj",
                age: 50,
                eyecolor: "black"
            }]
        };
        var cln_btn = '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="trailClick()">Click</button>';
        for (var x = 0; x < $scope.person.records.length; x++) {
            $scope.person.records[x].button = $sce.trustAsHtml(cln_btn);
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtl">
        <p>
            Click is not working in table
        </p>
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="value in person.records">
                    <td>{{value.firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{value.age}}</td>
                    <td bind-html-compile="value.button"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>
            When I click on Click button, My function should be call like below
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="trailClick()">Click</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5d60fe8MZqc1IfufV7nL?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot dude.. Its working. I will apply in my code by tomorrow.. :)